# AJAX Image upload with backbone.js node.js and express

Tags: node.js, file-upload, backbone.js, express

So I have been trawling the net for a day now trying to find a complete example of how to upload an image along with a normal POST (create) request from a backbone model.  So after some initial digging around I discovered the `FileReader` api in HTML5 - After some testing I had this working great outside backbone by creating a  `XMLHttpRequest()`

The problem im now trying to solve is how can I make bacbone send the FILES data along with the POST request like you would experience in a normal multipart form work flow.  Im pretty new to backbone so please forgive any obvious errors. Heres what I have so far.

## model

```
define(                                                                                                                                                
    [                                                                                                                                                  
        'backbone'                                                                                                                                     
    ],                                                                                                                                                 

    function (Backbone) {                                                                                                                              
        var Mock = Backbone.Model.extend({                                                                                                             
            url: '/api/v1/mocks',                                                                                                                      
            idAttribute: '_id',                                                                                                                        

            readFile: function(file){                                                                                                                  
                var reader = new FileReader();                                                                                                         
                self = this;                                                                                                                           

                reader.onload = (function(mockFile){                                                                                                   
                    return function(e){                                                                                                                
                        self.set({filename: mockFile.name, data: e.target.result});                                                                    
                    };                                                                                                                                 
                })(file);                                                                                                                              

                reader.readAsDataURL(file);                                                                                                            
            }                                                                                                                                          
        });                                                                                                                                            

        return Mock;                                                                                                                                   
    }                                                                                                                                                  
);
```

## view

```
define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'backbone',
        'underscore',
        'text!../templates/create_mock-template.html',
        'models/mock',
        'collections/mocks'
    ],

    function ($, Backbone, _, createMockTemplate, Mock, mocksCollection) {
        var CreateMockView = Backbone.View.extend({
            template: _.template(createMockTemplate),

            events: {
                'submit form': 'onFormSubmit',
                'click #upload-link': 'process',
                'change #upload': 'displayUploads'
            },

            initialize: function () {
                this.render();
                return this;
            },

            render: function () {
                this.$el.html(this.template);
            },

                        process: function(e){
                                var input = $('#upload');
                                if(input){
                                        input.click();
                                }
                                e.preventDefault();
                        },

                        displayUploads: function(e){
                                // Once a user selects some files the 'change' event is triggered (and this listener function is executed)
                                // We can access selected files via 'this.files' property object.

                                var formdata = new FormData();
                                var img, reader, file;
                                var self = this;

                                for (var i = 0, len = e.target.files.length; i < len; i++) {
                                        file = e.target.files[i];

                                        if (!!file.type.match(/image.*/)) {
                                                if (window.FileReader) {
                                                        reader = new FileReader();
                                                        reader.onloadend = function (e) { 
                                                                self.createImage(e.target.result, e);
                                                        };
                                                        self.file = file;
                                                        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                                                }
                                        }   
                                }
                        },

                        createImage: function(source, fileobj) {
                                var image = '<img src="'+source+'" class="thumbnail" width="200" height="200" />'
                                this.$el.append(image);
                        },

            onFormSubmit: function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                // loop through form elements
                var fields = $(e.target).find('input[type=text], textarea');
                var data = {};

                // add names and vlaues to data object
                $(fields).each(function(i, f) {
                    data[$(f).attr('name')] = $(f).attr('value');
                }); 

                // create new model from data
                var mock = new Mock(data);

                // this should set the filename and data attributes on the model???
                mock.readFile(this.file);

                // save to the server
                mock.save(null, {
                    wait: true,
                    error: function(model, response) {
                        console.log(model)
                    },
                    success: function(model, response) {
                        mocksCollection.add(model);
                        console.log(model, response);
                    }
                });
            },
        });

        return CreateMockView;
    }
);
```

I totally appreciate this may all be a bit hand wavey, its more a proof of concept than anything else and a good chance to learn backbone too.  So the crux of my question is this

- When the request is sent by backbone to the api why arent I seeing the data and filename attrs in the request to the node/express server
- Is what im trying to do even possible, I basically thought i'd be able to read the data attr and create and image on the server?
- Is there a way to perhaps overide the sync method on the Mock model and create a properly formed request where POST and FILES are correctly set.

Im sure this is possible but I just cant seem to find the bit of info I need to plough on and get this working.!

Hope someone can help!

CHEERS

## edit

Just wanted to provide a bit more info as by my understanding and some brief chats on the document cloud irc channel this should work.  So when I call

```
mock.readFile(this.file)
```

the fileName and data attributes dont seem to get set.  In fact a console log here dosent even seem to fire so im guessing this could be the problem.  I would be happy with this approach to basically build up the Image on the node end based on the value of data and fileName.  So why arent these properties being set and passed along in the post request to the api?

Answer (score 3):

I have resolved this situation splitting the Model creation in two steps:

1. Basic information
2. Assets

For example if my *Model* is a *Film*, I show a *create-form* that only include *title* and *synopsis*. This information is sent to the server and create the Model. In the next step I can show the *update-form* and now is very easier to use *File Uploads* plugins like:

- [jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/) Very profesional and stable
- [BBAssetsUpload](http://fguillen.github.com/BBAssetsUpload/) Very beta, but based on Backbone, and you can say you know the programmer ;P

You can also check their source code for references to try to achieve a *one-step Backbone Model with File creation* solution.

Comment: hey @fguillen thanks for the reply. Did you see my edit reagrding the data and fileName not being set on the model thus not being passed to the api in the post request.  I think it would be a good enought solution to be able to build the image from the readAsDataUrl data... this is driving me insane. cant see why this isnt working!  its something wrong with the readFile method on the mock model which gets called in the view im sure of it

Comment: @MikeWaites to try to solve the issue I should re-create the issue in a working code and this could be too much work for me, if you come back with a working code in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or something I could try to look on it. Make a ping here if you make it.

Answer (score 0):

[jquery-file-upload-middleware](https://github.com/aguidrevitch/jquery-file-upload-middleware) for express is probably worth mentioning.